# How can i solve data mismatching problem while sending data(which is taken through SPI protocol) from ESP32 to Android in ESP32 module?

Tags: c++, wifi, esp32, spi

First i am taking the data through SPI protocol then sending this data to android. But the problem is sending data to the android is taking some time(Milli seconds) then the data which is taking through SPI is mismatching in the indexes of array.

```
/*********************************************************************************/
#include <ESP32SPISlave.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

ESP32SPISlave slave;

#define StatusLED 27
const char* ssid     = "YOUR_ID";
const char* password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";

WiFiServer server(80);

IPAddress local_IP(192,168,3,14);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,3,5);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

static constexpr uint32_t BUFFER_SIZE {10};
uint8_t spi_slave_tx_buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
uint8_t spi_slave_rx_buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
uint8_t spi_slave_rx_Localbuf[BUFFER_SIZE];
uint32_t Client_buf[4];
bool WIFI_Flag;

byte count = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(2000);

    // LED init
    pinMode(StatusLED, OUTPUT);

    // HSPI = CS: 15, CLK: 14, MOSI: 13, MISO: 12 -> default
    // VSPI = CS: 5, CLK: 18, MOSI: 23, MISO: 19
    slave.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
    slave.begin();

    // clear buffers
    memset(spi_slave_tx_buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    memset(spi_slave_rx_buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    // We start by connecting to a WiFi network

  Serial.print("Setting AP (Access Point)…");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPConfig(local_IP,gateway,subnet)?"Ready" : "Failed!");

  //*server = start_webserver();
  Serial.print("Starting Access Point)…");
  Serial.println( WiFi.softAP(ssid, password)?"Ready" : "Failed!");
  
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());
  server.begin();

}

void loop() {
    // Switch OFF LED
    // Switch ON LED
    digitalWrite(StatusLED, HIGH);  // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    
    
    if (slave.remained() == 0) {
        slave.queue(spi_slave_rx_buf, spi_slave_tx_buf, BUFFER_SIZE);
    }  

    // if transaction has completed from master,
    // available() returns size of results of transaction,
    // and buffer is automatically updated

    if (slave.available()) {

        // Switch ON LED
        digitalWrite(StatusLED, LOW);  // turn the LED off (LOW is the voltage level)  
        

        if(count != 0)
        {
          switch(count)
                {
                  case 1: {Client_buf[0]   =  spi_slave_rx_buf[0]; break;}
                  case 2: {Client_buf[0]  |=  spi_slave_rx_buf[0] << 8; break;}
                  case 3: {Client_buf[1]   =  spi_slave_rx_buf[0]; break;}
                  case 4: {Client_buf[1]  |=  spi_slave_rx_buf[0] << 8; break;}
                  case 5: {Client_buf[2]   =  spi_slave_rx_buf[0]; break;}
                  case 6: {Client_buf[2]  |=  spi_slave_rx_buf[0]<<8;  break;}
                  case 7: {Client_buf[3]   =  spi_slave_rx_buf[0]; break;}
                  case 8: {Client_buf[3]  |=  spi_slave_rx_buf[0]<<8; WIFI_Flag = 1; break;}
                }
        }
       count++;
        
        slave.pop();
    }

        if(WIFI_Flag)
        {
          WiFiClient client = server.available();     
          
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-type:text/html");
          client.println("");
                   
            client.print(Client_buf[0]); 
            client.print(","); 
            client.print(Client_buf[1]); 
            client.print(","); 
            client.print(Client_buf[2]); 
            client.print(","); 
            client.print(Client_buf[3]); 
          WIFI_Flag = 0;
          count = 0;
        }        
}
/*********************************************************************************/
```

I tried to fix data mismatching in the indexes of array but i am not able to fix this issue. So, Could you please help me to solve this problem

Comment: what exactly is "data mismatching in the indexes of array" ? Please include actual and expected output

Comment: I am taking data through SPI(ESP32 as Slave) from other microcontroller (Master) and sending that data to android client app using WI-FI as server. By the time i send received SPI data that i have stored in an array to android app using WI-FI i am loosing data from SPI (i.e., Array indexes are mismatched).